# Springboot validation not working in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, validation, kotlin

I'm creating a new Springboot application with different REST APIs. I'm trying to use validation for my input parameters, but it's not working. Even with the annotations, I'm being able to insert blank content in the name field. Does anyone knows what can be wrong?

I've searched a lot about this, and I saw a lot of stuff saying to do exactly what I did. I've already tried to use @field:NotNull and @field:Size(min=1), and I have the same problem.

My controller:

```
@PostMapping
    @Operation(summary = "Insert a new client")
    fun insert(@Valid @RequestBody clientDTO : ClientInputDTO) : ResponseEntity<Void> {
        val client = clientService.fromInputDTO(clientDTO)
        val personInserted = personService.insert(client.person)
        client.person.addresses.forEach {
            it.person=personInserted
            addressService.insert(it)
        }
        val clientInserted = clientService.insert(client)
        val uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(clientInserted.id).toUri()
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).build()
    }
```

My DTO:

```
class ClientInputDTO(@JsonProperty("name")
                     @field:NotEmpty(message="name validation test")
                     val name: String,
                     @JsonProperty("person_type")
                     val personType: String,
                     @JsonProperty("document")
                     val document: Long,
                     @JsonProperty("rg")
                     val rg: String?,
                     @JsonProperty("addresses")
                     val addresses: List<AddressInputDTO>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Baledung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation#the-maven-dependencies) starting with Spring Boot 2.3 you need to explicitly add the spring-boot-starter-validation dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

Can you confirm you have this dependency on your project, so we can investigate further?